# A general question about precession

Tags: rotational-dynamics, definition, rigid-body-dynamics, precession

Does [precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) (of a top for example) occur only whenever the angular velocity vector is not parallel to a principal axis? I have yet found any clear definition of precession and when it is **defined** to occur.
If so, why does that imply that whenever the angular velocity vector is parallel to the angular momentum vector, there will not be any precession?

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the physics taking place:
When the spin axis and the torque axis coincide then any work that the torque is doing will go into changing the *rate of spin*, instead of inducing precession.

In order to be in a position to induce precession the axis of the torque must be non-aligned with the spin axis.

Whatever definition is used, it must be compatible with the above.